# what do you think about that comment delete screen UX/UI?

Tags: android, popup, comments, delete

we have an android app that lets you share thoughts with friends without revealing who you are. It's in developing processes now!
I designed comments delete screen, but I'm not sure it's good for UX.
What do you think about?

[image: comment delete screen]

Comment: It is better to delete without confirmation but provide an ability to undo the deletion (using a small notification or something). It's much more convenient way for deletion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The major issue here is I don't know how to answer the question about deletion. You've asked the question in plain English, but I assume you are expecting me to answer in symbolic form. Do I click the 'trash symbol' to delete the message? It would be much clearer if the symbol was appended with the words "Yes, delete this comment". How do I cancel? There's no button to do that.

Also, you should perhaps place the comment under the question, and place the buttons last. Using the word "this" in your question is referring to something that is 2 objects away. Whenever you use the word "this", the object to which you are referring to should be adjacent to the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

The final word on confirmation dialogs is given in the article [*Never use a warning when you mean undo*](http://alistapart.com/article/neveruseawarning) by Aza Raskin on A List Apart. Here's the key idea:

- **People habituate**: they press 'yes' without thinking, because 99% of the time that's what they want. The confirmation dialog isn't effective at asking for the required attention.
- People shouldn't have to give their attention to the task, if it's a mindless flow 99% of the times.
- **An undo option is much better**. People can follow their flow mindlessly and when they've accidentally deleted something, you give them the undo option.

The undo option actually eliminates the risk, instead of providing false safety and annoying users.

Comment: While undo is certainly better - sometimes it's not always feasible to technological constraints / limitations. Of course in that case the decision is a trade off between tech vs. better experience.

Answer (score 0):

I like your design, but in my opinion it seems a little dangerous to place an invitation to delete content above the content itself. There are exceptions to this rule but generally I think it would be safer to place it beneath.

Further to Brendon's answer, I think you could condense this further to just the one button: the word "Delete", with the trash icon to the left / above it. It's maybe just me, but I would be comfortable just tapping in the greyed out area to cancel / go back.

Comment: A cancel option should have more visual weight than an irreversible action such as delete, so that the user doesn't accidentally click the irreversible action. Clicking on the greyed out area is too ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options...

1- Change the text to alert the user to what he is about to do " Are you sure you want to delete, because, you will lose this information..." as an example. Then give the user two options: "No" / "Yes". But in this situation, the user will probably click the "yes" option as Peter mentioned, because users do not read and are used to the "yes" as if it was a "Continue" action.

2 - Therefore having a screen where the user has an undo option would be the best solution in my opinion. In this case we wouldn't need the screen A1 at all.

In the examples below I created a screen where the user is being asked if he wants to save. If he clicks "yes" he will only get an automatic confirmation message that the information was not saved.

The best option is a screen with a "undo" option... Option B.

I want to get some ground biography about these points and would be happy if someone would list some books and sources here, please.

[image: Solutions]